# convert sound from microphone input into note in real time using AudioKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audiokit

I am trying to convert sound from microphone input into note in real time. 
I am using code from example I found on AudioKit [Microphone Analysis](http://audiokit.io/examples/MicrophoneAnalysis) . It is working. However I have several questions:

Added the code for simplicity below.

```
//init
let mic = AKMicrophone()
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic, hopSize: 64.0, peakCount: 1050.0)
silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)

//viewDidAppear()
AudioKit.output = silence
AudioKit.start()
```

My app should work with human vocal only (like karaoke) with have frequency range from from `65.4064 (C2)  to 1046.5 (C6)`. I am not sure about `hopSize` and `peakCount` and what appropriate values they should have. However, the "Microphone Analysis" example above uses `KFrequencyTracker` init method with `minimumFrequency` and `maximumFrequency` as parameters which is not exist in the last version of the lib.

Consequently, I use `tracker.frequency` to determine the note in my app.

The questions are:

1. What the most appropriate approach to complete the task using AudioKit? Is my code above correct?

My Environment:

1. IOS Application (iPhone, iPad)
2. IOS 11.2
3. Swift 4
4. AudioKit ~> 4.0

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a real-time microphone singing detection app using AudioKit please see this tutorial: 
https://audiokitpro.com/build-a-singing-tutor-app-with-audiokit/

[image]

The fine folks at swifting.io have made a complete example app and tutorial blog post to demonstrate how to build a singing tutor. This code is similar to what might be used in a karaoke app. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for good example. I use similar approach to detect vocal voice range an note as in your project.  I can share same code when I finish with you as well If you would be interesting at. Frankly speaking prototype is already created and it can detect both notes and vocal ranges. However,  regarding AudioKit I just wondering is there any difference between AKFrequencyTracker and AKMicrophoneTracker?

Comment: Thanks! The AKFreqTracker vs AKMicTracker question would be good for Aurelius Prochazka if he's reading

Comment: Link is broken!